# Check if element has only one given class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

How to check (with jQuery) if an element has only one given class?

`$(#id).hasClass('class1')` returns `true` if the element has that class and another ones. How can I check if it has only THAT class?

Comment: You can use `attr()` to get _class_ attribute value and compare with the classname `$('#id').attr('class') === 'class1'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
$('#id')[0].classList
```

and you check check its length

```
$('#id')[0].classList.length == 1; //returns true if element has only one class
```

Now check if only one class is present by combining

```
$('#id').hasClass('class1') && $('#id')[0].classList.length == 1
```

Alternatively you can also simply check

```
$('#id')[0].className == 'class1'
```

Comment: It says there's an error near "&& $(#id)". "Ilegal character"

Comment: @AndrésBuitrago check again now

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of all classes like this:

```
var classList = $('#Id').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
if(classList.length == 1)
   //do something
```

Answer (score 1):

With only javascript and [**classList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) you can get the number

```
var _a = document.getElementById("demo");
var _cl = _a.classList.length;
document.write('<pre>'+_cl+'</pre>')
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/ge7z9y4y/1/)

Answer (score 1):

selector below is selecting what you need

```
$('#id[class="desiredClass"]')
```

check this example 
http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/MeeYbQ

Answer (score 0):

$('#footer').attr('class').split(' ').length